# Using react-redux with i18next?

Tags: reactjs, i18next

My project needs to be translated to many different languages so I chose [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation) to manage translations in my react app. I am new to the react ecosystem so please bear with me.

My react app has nested components and as I understand it, I need to pass down the props from the [i18next provider](https://react.i18next.com/components/i18nextprovider) recursively. Wouldn't be easier to manage the props with redux? As I am able to simply map the props to the state of the app without stringing along these props. Also could use reducers to manage what the current locale is.

Answer (score 2):

The point is not everything must be put into redux state. i18next already holds all translations and language (state).

What it does is pass down a translation function (which could not be put in redux state) -> as i18next holds state itself there is no need to pass language and messages to it (as you would have to do with the redux state).

The I18nextProvider does only pass down the i18n instance via context. The provided translate HOC or I18n render prop are there to optionally load translations via xhr and make sure those are loaded before rendering (if you preload all translations or bundle them with your app - there is no need for them and you could directly use an imported i18next).